# Mongo query to find documents which have date less than a particular date and delete it

Tags: mongodb, spring-boot, mongodb-query, spring-data-mongodb, mongotemplate

So this is my data in mongodb

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("60f67dc955784b233692a0f2"),
    "Id" : "9153",
    "InfoList" : [ 
        {
            "itemId" : "42342",
            "price" : 1009.0,
            "date" : ISODate("2021-01-01T08:30:36.131Z")
        }
    ]
}
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("6105668a55784bd00ef3ebc6"),
    "Id" : "894249",
    "InfoList" : [ 
        {
            "itemId" : "42342",
            "price" : 23.0,
            "date" : ISODate("2021-01-01T08:30:36.131Z")
        }, 
        {
            "itemId" : "3221",
            "price" : 44554.0,
            "date" : ISODate("2013-07-31T15:05:10.042Z")
        }
    ]
}
```

I want to find all the items in **InfoList** for all the documents whose date is less than *2021-02-09* and then delete them.

This is the code that I am using

```
Query query = new Query();
query.addCriteria(Criteria.where("InfoList")
                .elemMatch(Criteria
                .where("date")
                .lte(date)));
        return mongoTemplate.findAllAndRemove(query,ProductInfo.class, CollectionName);
```

But this code is neither finding the documents which have date < 2021-02-01 nor deleting them. Any suggestions regarding what might be wrong here ?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not familiar with Mongo query I know mongoose more
But do it like this 1-get all the of the object
It will return an array
On this array
2-do an if to check if the date is less than 2021-02-09 if yes remove it using its id

Comment: But the itemId can be same in multiple docs. consider itemId = 42342. It is present in 1st documnet and 2nd document